# For loop assigning only the last value of an array to eventlisteners

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, for-loop

I have the following AngularJS controller;

```
app.controller('playerController', ['$scope', '$http', 'playerService', function ($scope, $http, playerService) {
     $scope.soundeffects = playerService.getSoundeffects();

     function soundeffectCreation() {
        var maxrows = 3;
        var n = 0;

        var buttonTable = "<table class='table text-center'><tr>";

        for (var item = 0; item < $scope.soundeffects.length; item++) {
            var soundeffect = $scope.soundeffects[item];
            var soundeffectName = soundeffect.name;
            buttonTable += "<td><label>" + soundeffectName + "</label><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block' id='" + soundeffectName + "'><i class='fa fa-play'></i></button></td>"
             if(n == maxrows) {
                buttonTable += "</tr><tr>"
                n = 0;
             }
             else{
                n++;
            }
        }
        buttonTable += "</tr></table>";
        document.getElementById('soundeffects').innerHTML = buttonTable;

         for (var item = 0; item < $scope.soundeffects.length; item++) {
             var soundeffect = $scope.soundeffects[item];
             var soundeffectName = soundeffect.name;
             var button = document.getElementById(soundeffectName);

             console.log(soundeffect);
             console.log(soundeffectName);
             console.log(button);
             button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                console.log(soundeffectName);
            })
        }
    }

    soundeffectCreation();
}
```

It's working its magic on the following HTML:

```
<div id="soundeffects"></div>
```

Using a JSON array that so far only contains 3 items:

```
{
   "soundeffects": [
      {
        "name": "Wilhelm Scream",
        "video": "r6JK-gRELI0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fireball",
        "video": "AHRf27GPhQc"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mario Jump",
        "video": "37-paiEz0mQ"
      }
   ]
}
```

This JSON is retrieved succesfully in the playerService.
The buttons in the table are created just fine, they get their respective labels and the id's are assigned correctly, the problem appears in the second for-loop.
(The reason there's a second for-loop is because I can't add eventlisteners before the table is actually created).

The first three console.log's outside of the addEventListener return the correct values: [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd7YB.jpg)

Three different Objects with their respective names and videos.
Three different Names (Wilhelm Scream, Fireball & Mario Jump).
Three different buttons with the id's equal to the names described above.

However, when I click the created buttons, each of them returns "Mario Jump",  the last value of the array, instead of the name of the respective element. This despite the id's of the buttons being correct and everything. Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

As an alternative I tried putting `ng-click='$scope.playSoundeffect(" + soundeffect + ")'` in the original button creator, but that puts soundeffect in there as simply `[Object object]`. Any suggestions on how to make that method work would be welcome aswell.

---

**EDIT FOR POSTERITY**

After getting a bit more AngularJS experience I remade this entire section. I removed the entire `soundeffectCreation()` function and replaced it with the following html:

```
<div ng-repeat="soundeffect in soundeffects track by $index" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="text-nowrap"><label>{{soundeffect.name}}</label></div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="playSoundeffect(soundeffect)">
            <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids can't have spaces in them

Comment: Remember `var` isn't block scoped. Use `let` or create a closure inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var` inside for loop:

```
for (let item = 0; item < $scope.soundeffects.length; item++) {
     let soundeffect = $scope.soundeffects[item];
     let soundeffectName = soundeffect.name;
     let button = document.getElementById(soundeffectName);

     console.log(soundeffect);
     console.log(soundeffectName);
     console.log(button);
     button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log(soundeffectName);
    })
}
```

The problem was lack of distinct closure for each loop iteration - please check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for detailed explanation of closures in `for` loops.

**Solution for browsers that doesn't support `let`**

You can also use self-invoking anonymous function to create new scope for each iteration:

```
for (var item = 0; item < $scope.soundeffects.length; item++) {
     (function(i) {
         var soundeffect = $scope.soundeffects[i];
         var soundeffectName = soundeffect.name;
         var button = document.getElementById(soundeffectName);

         console.log(soundeffect);
         console.log(soundeffectName);
         console.log(button);
         button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log(soundeffectName);
        })
     })(item);
}
```

Comment: good solution, but check http://caniuse.com/#feat=let, browser support isnt 100%. So depends on browser support requirements.

Comment: Answer updated with solution for older browsers that doesn't support `let`

Comment: Browser support requirements are minimal. It's mostly for me and some tech-minded friends who keep their browsers up to date, so both work perfect for me. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture `soundeffectName` in closure like this

```
button.addEventListener('click', function (soundeffectName) {
    console.log(soundeffectName);
}.bind(null, soundeffectName))
```

Answer (score 0):

you're dealing with closures

```
 var soundeffectName = soundeffect.name;

 button.addEventListener('click', function () {
     console.log(soundeffectName);
 })
```

`soundEffect` is a variable of the outer scope, all the listeners will hold a reference to the outer scope, and they will all point the the same location in memory that is the value of the last iteration. to keep a copy of the value inside the listener try wrapping your code inside an IIFE

```
(function(name){
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log(name);
  })
})(soundeffectName)
```